# Bus Error in RMagick when using Rack?

Tags: ruby, rack, rmagick

Running either alone works fine, but when running both together, it crashes hard, at what seems like `Magick::Image#new` (the first call I make to it).

Edit: Request for code fulfilled below:

Under Ramaze, the issue can be reproduced like this

```
require 'ramaze'
require 'rmagick'

class ExceptionCauser < Ramaze::Controller
map '/'

  def index
    img = Magick::Image.new(64, 64)
  end

end

Ramaze.start :port => 7004
```

and then visiting `0.0.0.0:7004` will crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be fixed by recompiling Imagemagick using the `--disable-openmp` flag, as in [Why is this RMagick call generating a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838307/why-is-this-rmagick-call-generating-a-segmentation-fault) .