# rmagick leads to server shutdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick, carrierwave

everyone! I was following [Railscasts episode #253](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads), using CarrierWave to do **image upload.**

Everything was fine to display the original image, even though the image looked quite big in the browser.

I strictly followed Ryan Bates' instructions. But, when I tried to **resize** the image using **rmagick** and press upload button, I always got **server shutdown**. 
I am using rmagick 2.13.1
And I followed [this blog's instruction](http://weblogs.manas.com.ar/mverzilli/2010/05/19/install-the-rmagick-gem-in-the-painless-way-with-homebrewinstall-the-rmagick-gem-in-the-painless-way-with-homebrewinstall-the-rmagick-gem-in-the-painless-way-with-homebrewinstall-the-rmagick-gem-in/) to install homebrew, and imagemagick on my mac.

The error message is shown below.

```
    Rendered /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-

3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.9ms)
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:248: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0097 p:---- s:0482 b:0482 l:000481 d:000481 CFUNC  :read
c:0096 p:0054 s:0478 b:0478 l:000477 d:000477 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:248
c:0095 p:0011 s:0469 b:0469 l:000468 d:000468 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:132
c:0094 p:0044 s:0464 b:0464 l:000453 d:000463 BLOCK  /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:83
c:0093 p:---- s:0459 b:0459 l:000458 d:000458 FINISH
c:0092 p:---- s:0457 b:0457 l:000456 d:000456 CFUNC  :each
c:0091 p:0037 s:0454 b:0454 l:000453 d:000453 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:81
c:0090 p:0015 s:0450 b:0450 l:000441 d:000449 BLOCK  /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18
c:0089 p:---- s:0447 b:0447 l:000446 d:000446 FINISH
c:0088 p:---- s:0445 b:0445 l:000444 d:000444 CFUNC  :each
c:0087 p:0059 s:0442 b:0442 l:000441 d:000441 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18
c:0086 p:0091 s:0437 b:0437 l:000436 d:000436 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:107
c:0085 p:0035 s:0433 b:0433 l:000423 d:000432 BLOCK  /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:215
c:0084 p:---- s:0429 b:0429 l:000428 d:000428 FINISH
c:0083 p:---- s:0427 b:0427 l:000426 d:000426 CFUNC  :each
c:0082 p:0055 s:0424 b:0424 l:000423 d:000423 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:213
c:0081 p:0015 s:0419 b:0419 l:000410 d:000418 BLOCK  /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18
c:0080 p:---- s:0416 b:0416 l:000415 d:000415 FINISH
c:0079 p:---- s:0414 b:0414 l:000413 d:000413 CFUNC  :each
c:0078 p:0059 s:0411 b:0411 l:000410 d:000410 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18
c:0077 p:0091 s:0406 b:0406 l:000405 d:000405 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:107
c:0076 p:0019 s:0402 b:0402 l:000401 d:000401 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:317
c:0075 p:0021 s:0397 b:0397 l:000396 d:000396 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:173
c:0074 p:0054 s:0393 b:0393 l:000392 d:000392 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:37
c:0073 p:0081 s:0388 b:0388 l:000378 d:000387 BLOCK  /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1564
c:0072 p:---- s:0384 b:0384 l:000383 d:000383 FINISH
c:0071 p:---- s:0382 b:0382 l:000381 d:000381 CFUNC  :each
c:0070 p:0076 s:0379 b:0379 l:000378 d:000378 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1560
c:0069 p:0107 s:0372 b:0372 l:000371 d:000371 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1412
c:0068 p:---- s:0367 b:0367 l:000366 d:000366 FINISH
c:0067 p:---- s:0365 b:0365 l:000364 d:000364 CFUNC  :new
c:0066 p:0028 s:0361 b:0361 l:000360 d:000360 METHOD /Users/binyannie/rails/gallery_app/app/controllers/paintings_controller.rb:12
c:0065 p:0012 s:0358 b:0358 l:000357 d:000357 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4
c:0064 p:0015 s:0353 b:0353 l:000352 d:000352 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150
c:0063 p:0041 s:0348 b:0348 l:000347 d:000347 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11
c:0062 p:0012 s:0344 b:0344 l:002268 d:000343 BLOCK  /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18
c:0061 p:0063 s:0342 b:0342 l:000341 d:000341 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436
c:0060 p:0113 s:0336 b:0336 l:000335 d:000335 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410
c:0059 p:0024 s:0327 b:0327 l:000326 d:000326 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94
c:0058 p:0020 s:0321 b:0321 l:002268 d:002268 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17
c:0057 p:0012 s:0316 b:0316 l:000297 d:000315 BLOCK  /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30
c:0056 p:0017 s:0312 b:0312 l:000302 d:000311 BLOCK  /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52
c:0055 p:0032 s:0310 b:0310 l:000309 d:000309 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21
c:0054 p:0036 s:0303 b:0303 l:000302 d:000302 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52
c:0053 p:0152 s:0298 b:0298 l:000297 d:000297 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29
c:0052 p:0012 s:0292 b:0292 l:000291 d:000291 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17
c:0051 p:0093 s:0287 b:0287 l:000286 d:000286 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119
c:0050 p:0084 s:0281 b:0281 l:000280 d:000280 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41
c:0049 p:0048 s:0276 b:0276 l:000275 d:000275 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138
c:0048 p:0086 s:0271 b:0271 l:000270 d:000270 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14
c:0047 p:0030 s:0265 b:0265 l:000418 d:000264 BLOCK  /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178
c:0046 p:---- s:0262 b:0262 l:000261 d:000261 FINISH
c:0045 p:---- s:0260 b:0260 l:000259 d:000259 CFUNC  :call
c:0044 p:0022 s:0256 b:0256 l:000255 d:000255 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62
c:0043 p:0094 s:0250 b:0250 l:000249 d:000249 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27
c:0042 p:0097 s:0244 b:0244 l:000216 d:000243 BLOCK  /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148
c:0041 p:0014 s:0238 b:0238 l:000222 d:000237 BLOCK  /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93
c:0040 p:0189 s:0233 b:0233 l:000232 d:000232 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68
c:0039 p:0198 s:0223 b:0223 l:000222 d:000222 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92
c:0038 p:0092 s:0217 b:0217 l:000216 d:000216 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139
c:0037 p:0025 s:0211 b:0211 l:000210 d:000210 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493
c:0036 p:0015 s:0207 b:0207 l:000206 d:000206 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17
c:0035 p:0093 s:0200 b:0200 l:000199 d:000199 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14
c:0034 p:0155 s:0193 b:0193 l:000192 d:000192 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24
c:0033 p:0046 s:0187 b:0187 l:000186 d:000186 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21
c:0032 p:0054 s:0182 b:0182 l:000181 d:000181 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182
c:0031 p:0027 s:0175 b:0175 l:000174 d:000174 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149
c:0030 p:0015 s:0164 b:0164 l:000163 d:000163 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302
c:0029 p:0014 s:0156 b:0156 l:0016a0 d:000155 BLOCK  /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32
c:0028 p:0019 s:0154 b:0154 l:000153 d:000153 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.r
c:0027 p:0051 s:0150 b:0150 l:000149 d:000149 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12
c:0026 p:0019 s:0146 b:0146 l:0016a0 d:0016a0 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31
c:0025 p:0015 s:0142 b:0142 l:000141 d:000141 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_po
c:0024 p:0029 s:0138 b:0138 l:001660 d:000137 BLOCK  /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46
c:0023 p:0155 s:0136 b:0136 l:000135 d:000135 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416
c:0022 p:0011 s:0126 b:0126 l:001660 d:001660 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44
c:0021 p:0015 s:0122 b:0122 l:000121 d:000121 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107
c:0020 p:0049 s:0112 b:0112 l:000111 d:000111 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48
c:0019 p:0017 s:0108 b:0108 l:000107 d:000107 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47
c:0018 p:0027 s:0100 b:0100 l:000099 d:000099 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13
c:0017 p:0032 s:0096 b:0096 l:000095 d:000095 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17
c:0016 p:0052 s:0087 b:0087 l:000086 d:000086 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72
c:0015 p:0014 s:0083 b:0083 l:000077 d:000082 BLOCK  /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:11
c:0014 p:0019 s:0081 b:0081 l:000080 d:000080 METHOD <internal:prelude>:10
c:0013 p:0054 s:0078 b:0078 l:000077 d:000077 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:11
c:0012 p:0193 s:0073 b:0073 l:000072 d:000072 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30
c:0011 p:0032 s:0066 b:0066 l:000065 d:000065 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:168
c:0010 p:0021 s:0062 b:0062 l:000061 d:000061 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77
c:0009 p:---- s:0057 b:0057 l:000056 d:000056 FINISH
c:0008 p:0015 s:0055 b:0055 l:000054 d:000054 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14
c:0007 p:0015 s:0050 b:0050 l:000049 d:000049 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13
c:0006 p:0338 s:0042 b:0042 l:000041 d:000041 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52
c:0005 p:0257 s:0030 b:0030 l:000029 d:000029 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111
c:0004 p:0393 s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 METHOD /Users/binyannie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70
c:0003 p:0126 s:0009 b:0009 l:0023e8 d:000008 BLOCK  /Users/binyannie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:---- s:0002 b:0002 l:000001 d:000001 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__2758521140015343666__process_action__523965677563374240__callbacks'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
/Users/binyannie/rails/gallery_app/app/controllers/paintings_controller.rb:12:in `create'
/Users/binyannie/rails/gallery_app/app/controllers/paintings_controller.rb:12:in `new'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1412:in `initialize'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1560:in `attributes='
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1560:in `each'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1564:in `block in attributes='
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:37:in `image='
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:173:in `image='
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:317:in `cache'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:107:in `cache!'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `with_callbacks'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:213:in `cache_versions!'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:213:in `each'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:215:in `block in cache_versions!'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:107:in `cache!'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `with_callbacks'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:81:in `process!'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:81:in `each'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:83:in `block in process!'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:132:in `resize_to_limit'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:248:in `manipulate!'
/Users/binyannie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.7/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:248:in `read'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
```

I really have no clue why it is so. Anyone can give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: Can you make sure imagemagick is installed? `convert -version` should give you something like:

Version: ImageMagick 6.6.7-1 2011-07-20 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP

Comment: Yes. This is what I got. `Version: ImageMagick 6.7.1-1 2011-09-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP `

Comment: OK, try some of the methods on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838307/why-is-this-rmagick-call-generating-a-segmentation-fault

Comment: I am also running into this problem

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838307/why-is-this-rmagick-call-generating-a-segmentation-fault

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This fixed the problem for me (and I already had imagemagick installed via homebrew):

```
brew install -f imagemagick --disable-openmp
```

Give it a try.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. Cheers!

Comment: I also had to reinstall the `rmagick` gem after reinstalling imagemagick.

Comment: Thanks! Had to "brew uninstall imagemagick" first, otherwise got "Error: The linking step did not complete successfully" and then "Error: Cannot link imagemagick" when I tried to link as it suggested. Then reinstalled rmagick gem as suggested and no more error!