# Carrierwave Gem and rmagick

Tags: ruby, rubygems, xcode4.2, carrierwave, homebrew

I am having a bit of an issue and i am a little desperate. I have tried for days and all my efforts seem a little useless.

**GEM FILE**

```
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'carrierwave'
```

**XCODE TOOLS**

```
Version 4.2.1
```

**Gem list has gem included**

```
rmagick (2.13.1)
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-29 12:43:26 +0100
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:248: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0109 p:---- s:0561 b:0561 l:000560 d:000560 CFUNC  :read
c:0108 p:0054 s:0557 b:0557 l:000556 d:000556 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:248
c:0107 p:0025 s:0548 b:0548 l:000547 d:000547 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:185
c:0106 p:0044 s:0542 b:0542 l:000531 d:000541 BLOCK  /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:83
c:0105 p:---- s:0537 b:0537 l:000536 d:000536 FINISH
c:0104 p:---- s:0535 b:0535 l:000534 d:000534 CFUNC  :each
c:0103 p:0037 s:0532 b:0532 l:000531 d:000531 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:81
c:0102 p:0015 s:0528 b:0528 l:000519 d:000527 BLOCK  /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18
c:0101 p:---- s:0525 b:0525 l:000524 d:000524 FINISH
c:0100 p:---- s:0523 b:0523 l:000522 d:000522 CFUNC  :each
c:0099 p:0059 s:0520 b:0520 l:000519 d:000519 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18
c:0098 p:0091 s:0515 b:0515 l:000514 d:000514 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:112
c:0097 p:0035 s:0511 b:0511 l:000501 d:000510 BLOCK  /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:215
c:0096 p:---- s:0507 b:0507 l:000506 d:000506 FINISH
c:0095 p:---- s:0505 b:0505 l:000504 d:000504 CFUNC  :each
c:0094 p:0055 s:0502 b:0502 l:000501 d:000501 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:213
c:0093 p:0015 s:0497 b:0497 l:000488 d:000496 BLOCK  /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18
c:0092 p:---- s:0494 b:0494 l:000493 d:000493 FINISH
c:0091 p:---- s:0492 b:0492 l:000491 d:000491 CFUNC  :each
c:0090 p:0059 s:0489 b:0489 l:000488 d:000488 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18
c:0089 p:0091 s:0484 b:0484 l:000483 d:000483 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:112
c:0088 p:0019 s:0480 b:0480 l:000479 d:000479 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:317
c:0087 p:0021 s:0475 b:0475 l:000474 d:000474 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:173
c:0086 p:0054 s:0471 b:0471 l:000470 d:000470 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:37
c:0085 p:0069 s:0466 b:0466 l:000456 d:000465 BLOCK  /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1751
c:0084 p:---- s:0462 b:0462 l:000461 d:000461 FINISH
c:0083 p:---- s:0460 b:0460 l:000459 d:000459 CFUNC  :each
c:0082 p:0083 s:0457 b:0457 l:000456 d:000456 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1747
c:0081 p:0015 s:0450 b:0450 l:002668 d:000449 BLOCK  /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:162
c:0080 p:0015 s:0448 b:0448 l:0020e0 d:000447 BLOCK  /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295
c:0079 p:0232 s:0446 b:0446 l:000445 d:000445 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statem
c:0078 p:0025 s:0437 b:0437 l:000436 d:000436 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208
c:0077 p:0022 s:0432 b:0432 l:0020e0 d:0020e0 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293
c:0076 p:0015 s:0428 b:0428 l:002668 d:002668 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:161
c:0075 p:0022 s:0423 b:0423 l:002008 d:000422 BLOCK  /Users/tinkerbell/Ruby/secklow/app/controllers/updates_controller.rb:63
c:0074 p:---- s:0420 b:0420 l:000419 d:000419 FINISH
c:0073 p:---- s:0418 b:0418 l:000417 d:000417 CFUNC  :call
c:0072 p:0068 s:0414 b:0414 l:001e68 d:001e68 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:269
c:0071 p:0053 s:0407 b:0407 l:000406 d:000406 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:194
c:0070 p:0040 s:0401 b:0401 l:002008 d:002008 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/Ruby/secklow/app/controllers/updates_controller.rb:62
c:0069 p:0014 s:0398 b:0398 l:000397 d:000397 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4
c:0068 p:0015 s:0392 b:0392 l:000391 d:000391 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167
c:0067 p:0041 s:0387 b:0387 l:000386 d:000386 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10
c:0066 p:0010 s:0383 b:0383 l:000be0 d:000382 BLOCK  /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18
c:0065 p:0066 s:0381 b:0381 l:000380 d:000380 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416
c:0064 p:0113 s:0375 b:0375 l:000374 d:000374 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386
c:0063 p:0024 s:0366 b:0366 l:000365 d:000365 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81
c:0062 p:0020 s:0360 b:0360 l:000be0 d:000be0 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17
c:0061 p:0012 s:0356 b:0356 l:000355 d:000355 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17
c:0060 p:0010 s:0351 b:0351 l:000332 d:000350 BLOCK  /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30
c:0059 p:0017 s:0347 b:0347 l:000337 d:000346 BLOCK  /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53
c:0058 p:0032 s:0345 b:0345 l:000344 d:000344 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21
c:0057 p:0036 s:0338 b:0338 l:000337 d:000337 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53
c:0056 p:0152 s:0333 b:0333 l:000332 d:000332 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29
c:0055 p:0143 s:0328 b:0328 l:000327 d:000327 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201
c:0054 p:0032 s:0322 b:0322 l:000321 d:000321 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18
c:0053 p:0093 s:0317 b:0317 l:000316 d:000316 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121
c:0052 p:0084 s:0311 b:0311 l:000310 d:000310 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45
c:0051 p:0048 s:0306 b:0306 l:000305 d:000305 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193
c:0050 p:0086 s:0301 b:0301 l:000300 d:000300 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14
c:0049 p:0030 s:0295 b:0295 l:0003e8 d:000294 BLOCK  /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236
c:0048 p:---- s:0292 b:0292 l:000291 d:000291 FINISH
c:0047 p:---- s:0290 b:0290 l:000289 d:000289 CFUNC  :call
c:0046 p:0022 s:0286 b:0286 l:000285 d:000285 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65
c:0045 p:0094 s:0280 b:0280 l:000279 d:000279 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29
c:0044 p:0127 s:0274 b:0274 l:000245 d:000273 BLOCK  /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152
c:0043 p:0014 s:0267 b:0267 l:000251 d:000266 BLOCK  /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96
c:0042 p:0313 s:0262 b:0262 l:000261 d:000261 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75
c:0041 p:0137 s:0252 b:0252 l:000251 d:000251 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95
c:0040 p:0092 s:0246 b:0246 l:000245 d:000245 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141
c:0039 p:0025 s:0240 b:0240 l:000239 d:000239 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532
c:0038 p:0014 s:0236 b:0236 l:000227 d:000235 BLOCK  /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/warden-1.1.0/lib/warden/manager.rb:35
c:0037 p:---- s:0234 b:0234 l:000233 d:000233 FINISH
c:0036 p:---- s:0232 b:0232 l:000231 d:000231 CFUNC  :catch
c:0035 p:0086 s:0228 b:0228 l:000227 d:000227 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/warden-1.1.0/lib/warden/manager.rb:34
c:0034 p:0015 s:0223 b:0223 l:000222 d:000222 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17
c:0033 p:0015 s:0216 b:0216 l:000215 d:000215 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23
c:0032 p:0052 s:0208 b:0208 l:000207 d:000207 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35
c:0031 p:0093 s:0201 b:0201 l:000200 d:000200 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14
c:0030 p:0046 s:0194 b:0194 l:000193 d:000193 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21
c:0029 p:0054 s:0189 b:0189 l:000188 d:000188 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:247
c:0028 p:0031 s:0181 b:0181 l:000180 d:000180 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195
c:0027 p:0013 s:0173 b:0173 l:000172 d:000172 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190
c:0026 p:0020 s:0169 b:0169 l:000168 d:000168 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331
c:0025 p:0064 s:0161 b:0161 l:000160 d:000160 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64
c:0024 p:0029 s:0152 b:0152 l:000151 d:000151 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool
c:0023 p:0014 s:0144 b:0144 l:001a30 d:000143 BLOCK  /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29
c:0022 p:0155 s:0142 b:0142 l:000141 d:000141 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392
c:0021 p:0024 s:0132 b:0132 l:000131 d:000131 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81
c:0020 p:0013 s:0126 b:0126 l:001a30 d:001a30 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28
c:0019 p:0027 s:0122 b:0122 l:000121 d:000121 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68
c:0018 p:0015 s:0117 b:0117 l:000116 d:000116 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101
c:0017 p:0049 s:0107 b:0107 l:000106 d:000106 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48
c:0016 p:0017 s:0103 b:0103 l:000102 d:000102 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47
c:0015 p:0027 s:0095 b:0095 l:000094 d:000094 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13
c:0014 p:0155 s:0091 b:0091 l:000090 d:000090 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24
c:0013 p:0032 s:0085 b:0085 l:000084 d:000084 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17
c:0012 p:0057 s:0076 b:0076 l:000075 d:000075 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72
c:0011 p:0068 s:0072 b:0072 l:000071 d:000071 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15
c:0010 p:0124 s:0066 b:0066 l:000065 d:000065 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53
c:0009 p:0032 s:0060 b:0060 l:000059 d:000059 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:456
c:0008 p:0015 s:0056 b:0056 l:000055 d:000055 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14
c:0007 p:0015 s:0047 b:0047 l:000046 d:000046 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14
c:0006 p:0356 s:0042 b:0042 l:000041 d:000041 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59
c:0005 p:0257 s:0030 b:0030 l:000029 d:000029 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111
c:0004 p:0393 s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 METHOD /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70
c:0003 p:0126 s:0009 b:0009 l:001808 d:000008 BLOCK  /Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:---- s:0002 b:0002 l:000001 d:000001 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:331:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:247:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/warden-1.1.0/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/warden-1.1.0/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/warden-1.1.0/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.8.3/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201:in `process_action'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run__799694178329627303__process_action__4509060428211020593__callbacks'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
/Users/tinkerbell/Ruby/secklow/app/controllers/updates_controller.rb:62:in `update'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:194:in `respond_to'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:269:in `retrieve_response_from_mimes'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:269:in `call'
/Users/tinkerbell/Ruby/secklow/app/controllers/updates_controller.rb:63:in `block in update'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:161:in `update_attributes'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:162:in `block in update_attributes'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1747:in `assign_attributes'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1747:in `each'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1751:in `block in assign_attributes'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:37:in `pimage='
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:173:in `pimage='
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:317:in `cache'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:112:in `cache!'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `with_callbacks'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:213:in `cache_versions!'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:213:in `each'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:215:in `block in cache_versions!'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:112:in `cache!'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `with_callbacks'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:81:in `process!'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:81:in `each'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:83:in `block in process!'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:185:in `resize_to_fill'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:248:in `manipulate!'
/Users/tinkerbell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:248:in `read'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

This keeps on shutting down the server.  I have uninstalled xcode and reinstalled and i have also installed rmagick using homebrew. Can someone tell me what i am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer.

```
brew install -f imagemagick --disable-openmp
```

[rmagick leads to server shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319445/rmagick-leads-to-server-shutdown)
After all this typing and reading. Opphhhh

Answer (score 3):

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
brew install -f imagemagick --disable-openmp
```