# Gruff in RoR works in the console, crashes the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gruff

when I attempt to do this apparently common and simple graph generation in Ruby on Rails (Ruby 1.9.2, RoR 3.2.1):

```
@g = Gruff::Line.new
@g.title = "My Graph"
@g.data("Apples", [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3])
@g.data("Oranges", [4, 8, 7, 9, 8, 9])
@g.data("Watermelon", [2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 8])
@g.data("Peaches", [9, 9, 10, 8, 7, 9])
@g.labels = {0 => '2003', 2 => '2004', 4 => '2005'}
@g.write("fruitgraph.png")
```

it works in `rails console`, but when I put the same exact code in a function, say the show function for a page, and then navigate to that page, I get this error printout:

```
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:915: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0081 p:---- s:0441 b:0441 l:000440 d:000440 CFUNC  :initialize
c:0080 p:---- s:0439 b:0439 l:000438 d:000438 CFUNC  :new
c:0079 p:0048 s:0433 b:0433 l:000432 d:000432 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:915
c:0078 p:0085 s:0428 b:0428 l:000427 d:000427 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:898
c:0077 p:0123 s:0425 b:0425 l:000424 d:000424 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:318
c:0076 p:0114 s:0420 b:0419 l:000418 d:000418 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:333
c:0075 p:0138 s:0416 b:0416 l:000415 d:000415 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:195
c:0074 p:0105 s:0410 b:0410 l:000409 d:000409 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/line.rb:42
c:0073 p:---- s:0406 b:0406 l:000405 d:000405 FINISH
c:0072 p:---- s:0404 b:0404 l:000403 d:000403 CFUNC  :new
c:0071 p:0088 s:0401 b:0401 l:000400 d:000400 METHOD /Users/Tim/Dropbox/EmotionManager/manager/app/controllers/entries_controller.rb:26
c:0070 p:0014 s:0398 b:0398 l:000397 d:000397 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4
c:0069 p:0015 s:0392 b:0392 l:000391 d:000391 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167
c:0068 p:0041 s:0387 b:0387 l:000386 d:000386 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10
c:0067 p:0010 s:0383 b:0383 l:0025e0 d:000382 BLOCK  /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18
c:0066 p:0086 s:0381 b:0381 l:000380 d:000380 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414
c:0065 p:0113 s:0375 b:0375 l:000374 d:000374 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405
c:0064 p:0027 s:0366 b:0366 l:000365 d:000365 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385
c:0063 p:0024 s:0361 b:0361 l:000360 d:000360 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81
c:0062 p:0020 s:0355 b:0355 l:0025e0 d:0025e0 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17
c:0061 p:0012 s:0351 b:0351 l:000350 d:000350 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29
c:0060 p:0010 s:0346 b:0346 l:000327 d:000345 BLOCK  /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30
c:0059 p:0017 s:0342 b:0342 l:000332 d:000341 BLOCK  /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123
c:0058 p:0032 s:0340 b:0340 l:000339 d:000339 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20
c:0057 p:0036 s:0333 b:0333 l:000332 d:000332 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123
c:0056 p:0152 s:0328 b:0328 l:000327 d:000327 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29
c:0055 p:0143 s:0323 b:0323 l:000322 d:000322 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205
c:0054 p:0032 s:0317 b:0317 l:000316 d:000316 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18
c:0053 p:0093 s:0312 b:0312 l:000311 d:000311 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121
c:0052 p:0084 s:0306 b:0306 l:000305 d:000305 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45
c:0051 p:0048 s:0301 b:0301 l:000300 d:000300 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203
c:0050 p:0086 s:0296 b:0296 l:000295 d:000295 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14
c:0049 p:0030 s:0290 b:0290 l:000d18 d:000289 BLOCK  /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246
c:0048 p:---- s:0287 b:0287 l:000286 d:000286 FINISH
c:0047 p:---- s:0285 b:0285 l:000284 d:000284 CFUNC  :call
c:0046 p:0022 s:0281 b:0281 l:000280 d:000280 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66
c:0045 p:0094 s:0275 b:0275 l:000274 d:000274 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30
c:0044 p:0161 s:0269 b:0269 l:000252 d:000268 BLOCK  /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/journey-1.0.3/lib/journey/router.rb:68
c:0043 p:---- s:0258 b:0258 l:000257 d:000257 FINISH
c:0042 p:---- s:0256 b:0256 l:000255 d:000255 CFUNC  :each
c:0041 p:0051 s:0253 b:0253 l:000252 d:000252 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/journey-1.0.3/lib/journey/router.rb:56
c:0040 p:0025 s:0249 b:0249 l:000248 d:000248 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589
c:0039 p:0015 s:0245 b:0245 l:000244 d:000244 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:1
c:0038 p:0015 s:0238 b:0238 l:000237 d:000237 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:23
c:0037 p:0068 s:0230 b:0230 l:000229 d:000229 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25
c:0036 p:0093 s:0223 b:0223 l:000222 d:000222 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14
c:0035 p:0046 s:0216 b:0216 l:000215 d:000215 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21
c:0034 p:0054 s:0211 b:0211 l:000210 d:000210 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242
c:0033 p:0031 s:0203 b:0203 l:000202 d:000202 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205
c:0032 p:0013 s:0195 b:0195 l:000194 d:000194 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200
c:0031 p:0020 s:0191 b:0191 l:000190 d:000190 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338
c:0030 p:0064 s:0183 b:0183 l:000182 d:000182 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64
c:0029 p:0029 s:0174 b:0174 l:000173 d:000173 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connectio
c:0028 p:0014 s:0166 b:0166 l:002670 d:000165 BLOCK  /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28
c:0027 p:0040 s:0164 b:0164 l:000163 d:000163 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405
c:0026 p:0113 s:0157 b:0157 l:000156 d:000156 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405
c:0025 p:0027 s:0148 b:0148 l:000147 d:000147 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385
c:0024 p:0024 s:0143 b:0143 l:000142 d:000142 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81
c:0023 p:0013 s:0137 b:0137 l:002670 d:002670 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27
c:0022 p:0039 s:0133 b:0133 l:000132 d:000132 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65
c:0021 p:0044 s:0128 b:0128 l:000127 d:000127 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31
c:0020 p:0017 s:0124 b:0124 l:000123 d:000123 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16
c:0019 p:0017 s:0117 b:0117 l:000116 d:000116 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56
c:0018 p:0121 s:0111 b:0111 l:000110 d:000110 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26
c:0017 p:0052 s:0105 b:0105 l:000104 d:000104 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16
c:0016 p:0048 s:0101 b:0101 l:000100 d:000100 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22
c:0015 p:0095 s:0094 b:0094 l:000093 d:000093 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21
c:0014 p:0032 s:0089 b:0089 l:000088 d:000088 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17
c:0013 p:0057 s:0080 b:0080 l:000079 d:000079 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72
c:0012 p:0068 s:0076 b:0076 l:000075 d:000075 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15
c:0011 p:0124 s:0070 b:0070 l:000069 d:000069 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53
c:0010 p:0032 s:0064 b:0064 l:000063 d:000063 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:479
c:0009 p:0034 s:0060 b:0060 l:000059 d:000059 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:220
c:0008 p:0015 s:0056 b:0056 l:000055 d:000055 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14
c:0007 p:0015 s:0047 b:0047 l:000046 d:000046 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14
c:0006 p:0356 s:0042 b:0042 l:000041 d:000041 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59
c:0005 p:0257 s:0030 b:0030 l:000029 d:000029 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111
c:0004 p:0393 s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70
c:0003 p:0126 s:0009 b:0009 l:001f28 d:000008 BLOCK  /Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:---- s:0002 b:0002 l:000001 d:000001 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3357496781086114657__call__4342850330723582611__callbacks'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/journey-1.0.3/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/journey-1.0.3/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/journey-1.0.3/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `dispatch'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__3934952041362041186__process_action__2052907014529777029__callbacks'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
/Users/Tim/Dropbox/EmotionManager/manager/app/controllers/entries_controller.rb:26:in `show'
/Users/Tim/Dropbox/EmotionManager/manager/app/controllers/entries_controller.rb:26:in `new'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/line.rb:42:in `initialize'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:195:in `initialize'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:333:in `theme_keynote'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:318:in `theme='
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:898:in `render_background'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:915:in `render_gradiated_background'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:915:in `new'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tut/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:915:in `initialize'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

Any ideas or help would be great, thanks!

Comment: I've just run into this myself :( any luck yet?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for other RMagick issues seemed to work for me in OSX:

```
brew install -f imagemagick --disable-openmp
```

I found this on the posts [Why is this RMagick call generating a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838307/why-is-this-rmagick-call-generating-a-segmentation-fault) and [rmagick leads to server shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319445/rmagick-leads-to-server-shutdown).

I uninstalled imagemagick as well as the rmagick gem before installing. I didn't need the `-f` flag as other people mentioned, but I'm keeping it here for posterity.