# Rails 3.1 + Ruby 1.9.3-rc1 + Rmagick + CarrierWave = [BUG] Segmentation fault ruby 1.9.3dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick, carrierwave

I have a problem with carrier wave and Rmagick on OSX lion latest.
I get a full bug report below. Is there a workaround for this?

Installed rmagick with sudo gem install rmagick
Using Carrierwave to resize the images

Full bug report: ( due to char limit on stackoverflow )
http://pastebin.com/yVSn9SZZ

Comment: consider ruby 1.9.2 if it's an option.

Comment: Thats not an option due to the slowness I have upgraded to the latest rails, not sure if rails 1.9.3-rc1 is the latest currently have to look in to that. As always Rmagick keeps frustrating on OSX to install... each and every time :(

Comment: [ruby-]1.9.3-head is this a good choice to upgrade to?

Comment: You mean 1.9.3-rc1 already use that

Comment: @Rubytastic No, I mean 1.9.3-p0, just like I said.

Comment: That is not known to RVM ... how would I install that with RVM on osx?

Comment: Aah stupid completely missed that release, I'm not in the upgrade process hope it works away the rmagick issue, many things where fixed in that release i see from change log, thanks for pointing this out! I would have definitely missed it like before

Comment: UPGRADED to the latest version 1.9.3-p0 still the same!! damn :( this is really frustrating why doesn't rmagick work like it should do and do i get a 600 lines bug report where i can do nothing with to try and fix it since it a mess 600 lines long

Comment: Seems a duplicate I followed suggestions stated here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838307/why-is-this-rmagick-call-generating-a-segmentation-fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this fixed, it seemed a bug in latest rails.
I compiled everything again and used macports to compile imagemagick then it worked fine