# Rails: server crashes after installing image magick to use with Carrier Wave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave, webrick

I just installed image magick on my Mac to use with the Ruby CarrierWave gem. However, when I upload a file, the localhost/webrick server crashes with more than 1000 lines of error messages.  Before installing image magick, I could upload images without a problem (just not resize them obviously).

This is the first part of the error message

```
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-02-25 23:49:55] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@rails321/gems/carrierwave-0.5.8/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:248: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-09-23 revision 33323) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

at the bottom it says

```
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: If you are on Mac OS you should check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838307/why-is-this-rmagick-call-generating-a-segmentation-fault)  up.